# Camel Spring : No component found with scheme: sftp

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am trying to create component which move files from one location to another location using Camel Spring.

Its working fine for FTP, but it given error when trying with SFTP.

**Error is (SFTP URI : sftp://IP Address:Port/CamelTesting?username=testftp&password=testftp):** 
Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 25 in XML document from class path resource [processorApplicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 76; The reference to entity "password" must end with the ';' delimiter.

**Error is (SFTP URI (&amp): sftp://IP Address:Port/CamelTesting?username=testftp&password=testftp):** 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[sftp://IP Address:Port/CamelTesting?username=testftp&password=testftp] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:D:/Test/in]] -> [To[sftp:/IP Address:Port... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: sftp://IP Address:Port/CamelTesting?password=testftp&username=testftp due to: No component found with scheme: sftp

**Dependencies are :**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**testApplicationContext.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">       
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <!--FTP Working fine--> 
    <!--route>
        <from uri="file:D:/Test/in" />                          
        <to uri="file:D:/Test/out" />
    </route-->

     <!--SFTP--> 
     <route>
        <from uri="file:D:/Test/in" />          
        <to uri="sftp://<IP Address:Port>/CamelTesting?username=testftp&password=testftp"/>
    </route> 
</camelContext>
```

**Test Class :**

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class testSFTP {
public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("testApplicationContext.xml");
    CamelContext camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(appContext, false);
    try {
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        camelContext.stop();
        appContext.close();
    }
    }
}
```

can someone help me for resolve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in xml use `&amp;` as &

```
<route>
    <from uri="file:D:/Test/in" />          
    <to uri="sftp://<IP Address:Port>/CamelTesting?username=testftp&amp;password=testftp"/>
</route>
```

for secord Error:

You need to add camel-ftp to your classpath. just add it as dependency to the pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Hisham for replay.  I had tried with both &amp; and &. Please check by both error's.

Comment: After added camel ftp dependency, till it'w given same error messages.

Comment: So i reproduced your errors and by doing the steps i have mentioned above every thing works fine. have you rebuilt the application after the dependency had been added?

Comment: Thanks Hisham. Your Help Works.